next.js 14 How to use decoded url in app router (way to configure Korean URL)
My request 
http://localhost:3000/docs/시작하기
Next.js 
GET /docs/%EC%8B%9C%EC%9E%91%ED%95%98%EA%B8%B0 200 in 97ms
Is there a way to configure Korean URL addresses to be routed in Next.js?
I tried configuring the middleware... but ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS occurred, somebody help me!!

You can use Path Params to get the Korean content and then decode it using the decodeURIComponent method.
How to create this dynamic param:

Wrap the file or folder name in square brackets. For example, [KoreanInput] can represent docs slugs.
Access dynamic segments using useRouter().query.slug. Example route: /docs/[KoreanInput].js where { KoreanInput: '%EC%8B%9C%EC%9E%91%ED%95%98%EA%B8%B0' };
Now read it and decode it using decodeURIComponent(KoreanInput), it will return actual Korean Content.

Or

You can use rewrites in your next.config.js file
basically, you need to use i18n and then define routes like below:



    // next.config.js
    module.exports = {
        async rewrites() {
            return [
                {
                    source: '/docs/시작하기',
                    destination: '/docs/english-route',
                    locale: false
                }
            ];
        }
    };




I solved the problem using slug, Thank you!

app > docs > [category] > [mdx] > page.tsx

export default async function MDXRemotePage({params}: { params:
Params
}) {
const {category, mdx} = params;
const sidebar: Sidebar = sidebarJson
const decodeCategory = decodeURIComponent(category);
const item = decodeURIComponent(mdx);


if (sidebar[decodeCategory] && sidebar[decodeCategory].includes(item)) {
    const filePath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'docs', decodeCategory, `${item}.mdx`);
    try {
        const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8');
        return <MDXRemote components={useMDXComponents} source={fileContent} />;
    } catch (error) {
        return <div>File not found</div>;
    }
} else {
    return <div>Page Not Found</div>;
}

}

